# Flyway maven plugin, location with multiple modules

Tags: maven, flyway

I have the following problem.

I have maven multi modules project, with the following structure:

```
Parent
|
|_____DB-Setup
|        |______V1__init.sql
|        |______V1.1__update.sql
|
|_____Modul1
|        |____src/*
|            
|_____Modul2
         |____src/*
```

How can I using maven say Flyway that my SQL scripts located under Parrent/DB-Setap?

thx.

```
<!--FlyWay -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.flyway</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <url>jdbc:xxxx</url>
                <user>xxx</user>
                <password>xxx</password>
                <validateOnMigrate>true</validateOnMigrate>                   
            </configuration>               
        </plugin>
```

thx.

Answer (score 4):

You have three options:

1. Turn DB-Setup into a proper Maven module and let they other modules depend on it. Place the scripts under DB-Setup/src/main/resources. You will then be able to use both the Flyway Maven plugin and the API directly from the other modules.
2. Turn DB-Setup into a proper Maven module and execute the Flyway Maven plugin there.
3. Keep DB-Setup as a simple directory and use a filesystem: location in the Flyway Maven plugin configuration to refer to the path where the sql migrations are stored.

My preference is either #1 or #2.

Answer (score -1):

Flyway is looking in your `classpath` for the directory `db/migration`.

So if you put your scripts under `DB-Setup/db/resources` it should be fine.

Alternatively, you can override the `locations` property of Flyway like explained here:

http://flywaydb.org/documentation/migration/sql.html